# Is it possible to rotate the camera of Standard Assets' FirstPersonController with Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, minecraft

[image: Image1]

I want to rotate the camera of FPSController of Standard Assets on Android.
In FPSController there is a camera called FirstPersonCharacter and want to know whether to rotate it directly or with First Person Controller (C # Script).

I have already successfully operated FPSController with joystick of Standard Assets.

I hope to rotate the camera like Minecraft Pocket Edition.
[image: MinecraftPE]